# Theoretically, if you could attach a 1 meter string with a weight on the end to the exact center of the earth what would it do?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, mass

Would the mass of the weight keep moving towards the center but overshoot and repeat the process?

Comment: Yes, but immeasurably slow.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the string attached to? In your experiment, is there a hollowed-out region at the centre of the Earth?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the string is light in the usual way it serves no purpose (see below for why this is safe), so we can leave it out and just consider a mass moving.

Further I will assume that you are interested in how the mass would move in the gravitational field inside the Earth, if it was only influenced by gravity and could move without interacting with the material in the Earth (so, perhaps it is made out of some kind of souped-up neutrinos which *only* feel gravity).  So in particular I assume you don't want to know how the mass would move if all of the Earth's mass was concentrated at a point, which would just be the ordinary orbit problem.

I will assume that the Earth has a constant density, $\rho$ and is spherical: in real life neither is quite true, but this is how to make the problem answerable without hairy numerical modelling, and it's probably not a terrible approximation over small scales.

Finally I'll assume that the mass is initially at rest some distance $r_0$ (where $r_0 = 1\,\mathrm{m}$ in fact) from the centre of the system.  So in particular it has no tangential component of velocity.  This lets me model the problem in one dimension, trying to solve $r$ as a function of time.

So first of all we need to compute what the force is on the mass (call it $m$).  To do this we use the [shell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem) which tells us that the material outside the radius of the object does not matter, and we can model the mass inside it as if it were concentrated at a point.  This means that

$$
\begin{aligned}
F &= \frac{G m M}{r^2}\quad\text{$M$ is the mass inside $r$}\\
  &= \frac{G m}{r^2}\frac{4}{3} \pi r^3\quad\text{substituting expression for $M$}\\
  &= \frac{4\pi}{3}G\rho m r\quad\text{simplifying}
\end{aligned}
$$

OK, so now we have a nice second-order differential equation, via $F = ma$:

$$\frac{d^2 r}{d t^2} = \left(- \frac{4\pi}{3}G\rho\right) r$$

Well, this is something that you can solve, and, after some mucking around and getting the initial conditions right, you get an expression for $r$:

$$r = r_0 \cos\left(\left(\sqrt{\frac{4\pi}{3}G\rho}\right) t \right)$$

In other words, the motion is SHM, with the mass gradually moving towards, through, and away from the centre of the Earth.

Note that this is one of the reasons we can ignore the string: $r \le r_0$ always, so the string never becomes tight and this never constrains the motion.  So we can just ignore it.  This would not be true if the initial velocity was not zero of course.

We can compute the angular frequency:

$$
\begin{align}
 \omega &= \sqrt{\frac{4\pi}{3}G\rho}\\
        &\approx 0.001\,\mathrm{s^{-1}}\quad\text{using $\rho\approx 5500\,\mathrm{kg/m^3}$}
\end{align}
$$

And hence $f \approx 0.0002\,\mathrm{Hz}$.  This gives a period of about an hour and a half.

Note (see comment by Martin Kochanski) that this is independent of $r_0$: *any* object moving like this inside the Earth will have this period, even if it starts from the surface, say, and it's also the same as the orbital period of an object orbiting at the surface of the planet, which is a nice result.

---

Here's a neat argument as to why the period is the same as the period of a circular orbit at the surface.  Consider an object orbiting at radius $r$ using the obvious $(r,\theta)$ coordinates.  We know that $\ddot\theta = 0$, because there is never any force in that direction (the force is radial).  Projecting the motion into the obvious $x, y$ coordinates, this means that the motion, projected onto the $x$ axis is simple-harmonic, because $x = r\cos\theta$, and $\dot\theta$ is constant.  OK, now consider the object at $(r, 0)$, which in cartesian coordinates is also $(r, 0)$.  We know that at this point

$$
\begin{aligned}
  \dot x &= 0\\
  \ddot x &= -\frac{4\pi}{3}\rho G r
\end{aligned}
$$

So in summary: we know that the projection of the motion onto the $x$ axis is SHM, and we know the first and second derivatives of $x$ at the top of the motion.  That's enough to solve the period, and it's trivially the same as for a particle oscillating inside the planet.

Note that this is true for *any* $r$, not just $r = R$: it's true for circular orbits *inside* the planet as well for objects which only interact gravitationally!  I am not convinced that such orbits are stable though: someone will know this I am sure.

Comment: You are wrong about being wrong. The period of 90-ish minutes is correct, whether the mass starts 1m away from the centre of the Earth, or at the Earth's surface. It is also necessarily identical to the period of a satellite in a circular orbit at zero altitude.

Comment: @MartinKochanski Oh, thanks!  I 'knew' it was independent of distance (I mean, that's obvious because it's SHM) but I hadn't actually thought about what that meant and my mental model had the thing taking a very long time if it was very close to the centre.  I will update the answer.  Thanks again.

Comment: @MartinKochanski is there a simple way to see why this is true?

Comment: @user2723984: yes there is, I think. I will put it in the answer once I've convinced myself I'm right.